# findAll(Pageable) returns wrong sorting order

Tags: java, spring, sorting, repository

Why `PagingAndSortingRepository<City, Long>` return wrong sorting order after method `findAll(Pageable)`?
In service layer I have this method and I'm trying to sort by population:

```java
    public Set<City> findAllPageable(int page, int size, String sortBy) {
        Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(page, size, Sort.by(sortBy));
        return new HashSet<>(repository.findAll(paging).getContent());
    }
```

This is what I expected to see:

```sql
    select Population from city order by Population limit 10;
42
167
300
455
503
559
595
682
700
800
```

And this is the actual result after iterating the `Set<City>`:

```java
682, 42, 300, 700, 559, 595, 800, 167, 455, 503
```

All these numbers are correct but the order is incorrect. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't rely on the order elements are returned in a `HashSet`. If you must use a set there, use a [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), which guarantees the order:

```
return new LinkedHashSet<>(repository.findAll(paging).getContent());
```

Answer (score 1):

The returned `HashSet` implementation doesn't maintain the *sorting order* of the cities.

Use the `TreeSet` implementation and pass either a `Comparator<City>` or let `City` implement `Copmarable<City>`. I also suggest you to return `SortedSet<City>` in that case.

> The elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at set creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

```
public SortedSet<City> findAllPageable(int page, int size, String sortBy) {
     Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(page, size, Sort.by(sortBy));
     return new TreeSet<>(
         repository.findAll(paging).getContent(), 
         Comparator.comparing(City::getPopulation));
}
```